# Access newly created column in .with_columns() when using polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I am new to [polars](https://www.pola.rs) and I am not sure whether I am using `.with_columns()` correctly.

Here's a situation I encounter frequently:
There's a dataframe and in `.with_columns()`, I apply some operation to a column. For example, I convert some dates from `str` to `date` type and then want to compute the duration between start and end date. I'd implement this as follows.

```py
import polars as pl 

pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "start": ["01.01.2019", "01.01.2020"],
        "end": ["11.01.2019", "01.05.2020"],
    }
).with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("start").str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt="%d.%m.%Y"),
        pl.col("end").str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt="%d.%m.%Y"),
    ]
).with_columns(
    [
        (pl.col("end") - pl.col("start")).alias("duration"),
    ]
)
```

First, I convert the two columns, next I call `.with_columns()` again.

Something shorter like this does not work:

```py
pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "start": ["01.01.2019", "01.01.2020"],
        "end": ["11.01.2019", "01.05.2020"],
    }
).with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("start").str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt="%d.%m.%Y"),
        pl.col("end").str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt="%d.%m.%Y"),
        (pl.col("end") - pl.col("start")).alias("duration"),
    ]
)
```

Is there a way to avoid calling `.with_columns()` twice and to write this in a more compact way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second `.with_columns` is needed.

From [@DeanMacGregor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601543/access-newly-created-column-in-with-columns-when-using-polars#comment133382346_75601785)

> To elaborate, everything in a context (`with_columns` in this case) only knows about what's in the dataframe before the context was called. Each expression in a context is unaware of every other expression in the context. This is by design because all the expressions run in parallel. If you need one expression to know the output of another expression, you need another context.

You could pass multiple names to `.col()` and use named args instead of `.alias()`

```
(df
 .with_columns(
    pl.col("start", "end").str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt="%d.%m.%Y"))
 .with_columns(
    duration = pl.col("end") - pl.col("start")))
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│ start      | end        | duration     │
│ ---        | ---        | ---          │
│ date       | date       | duration[ms] │
╞════════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-11 | 10d          │
│ 2020-01-01 | 2020-05-01 | 121d         │
└────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! The `fmt` argument is slightly different for `start` and `end` in the actual data I use, but I'll keep the suggestions in mind :)

Comment: @Thomas To elaborate, everything in a context (`with_columns` in this case) only knows about what's in the dataframe before the context was called.  Each expression in a context is unaware of every other expression in the context.  This is by design because all the expressions run in parallel.  If you need one expression to know the output of another expression, you need another context.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @DeanMacGregor - I've added your comment to my answer as I think it's worthwhile information. Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a trick to make it seem like you're referencing a new column in an existing context.

You can use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html).

```
pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "start": ["01.01.2019", "01.01.2020"],
        "end": ["11.01.2019", "01.05.2020"],
    }
).with_columns(
    [
        (start := pl.col("start").str.strptime(pl.Date, "%d.%m.%Y")),
        (end := pl.col("end").str.strptime(pl.Date, "%d.%m.%Y")),
        (end - start).alias("duration"),
    ]
)
```

Note that I said this makes it *seem like* you're referencing the new column. What you're really doing is defining the expression for `start` to a global variable, the same for `end`. In the last expression when you're creating duration, it will compute each of start and end an extra time, (unless you're in lazy mode).

If you're in lazy mode then it will create what's called a CSER which is a cached version of each of `start` and `end` so it doesn't do redundant computations.

You can see that like this:

```
print(pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "start": ["01.01.2019", "01.01.2020"],
        "end": ["11.01.2019", "01.05.2020"],
    }
).lazy().with_columns(
    [
        (start:=pl.col("start").str.strptime(pl.Date, "%d.%m.%Y")),
        (end:=pl.col("end").str.strptime(pl.Date, "%d.%m.%Y")),
        (end - start).alias("duration"),
    ]
).explain())

WITH_COLUMNS:
 [col("__POLARS_CSER_14693840185675249975").alias("start"), col("__POLARS_CSER_9386772493530534005").alias("end"), [(col("__POLARS_CSER_9386772493530534005")) - (col("__POLARS_CSER_14693840185675249975"))].alias("duration"), col("start").str.strptime([Utf8(raise)]).alias("__POLARS_CSER_14693840185675249975"), col("end").str.strptime([Utf8(raise)]).alias("__POLARS_CSER_9386772493530534005")]
  DF ["start", "end"]; PROJECT */2 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
```