# Reference a polars column that will be created in the same with_columns block

Tags: python-polars

I'd like to reference a polars column just after creating it.
Is there a way to tell polars to wait for that execution untill all required columns exist?

```
pl_df = pl_df.with_columns(
    [
        (pl.col("arrival_is") - pl.col("arrival_should")).alias("delay_arrival_total"),
        (pl.col("departure_is") - pl.col("departure_should")).alias("delay_departure_total"),
        (pl.col("delay_departure_total") - pl.col("delay_arrival_total")).alias("delay_diff"),
    ]
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75601543